# Testing if Scheduling Operations is Possible Given Multiple Processors with Time Slots

Tags: algorithm

Given a set of operations that have start and end times and require a number of processors, and a set of processors that are available at start and end times does a polynomial algorithm exist to determine if all the tasks can be run? As a follow-up does a polynomial algorithm exist that returns a possible execution?

For example:

```
O1: 7:00 AM to 8:00 AM - req. 2 × Processors
O2: 8:00 AM to 9:00 AM - req. 2 × Processors
O3: 7:00 AM to 9:00 AM - req. 2 × Processors
```

Can be run on the following processors

```
P1: 7:00 AM to 9:00 AM - runs O1 and O2
P2: 7:00 AM to 9:00 AM - runs O1 and O2
P3: 7:00 AM to 9:00 AM - runs O3
P4: 7:00 AM to 9:00 AM - runs O3
```

But cannot be run on the following processors:

```
P1: 7:00 AM to 8:00 AM
P2: 8:00 AM to 9:00 AM
P3: 7:00 AM to 9:00 AM
P4: 7:00 AM to 9:00 AM
```

Note: it isn't possible to switch processors for an operation.

I believe it might be a related to either the [Job Shop Scheduling (JSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling) and [Nurse Scheduling Problem (NSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nurse_scheduling_problem) however both seem slightly different.

For both JSP and NSP the key difference is that there is no min / max requirement (and we don't care about the optimal solution - just if a solution exists).

Answer (score 0):

You are interested in a small variation of the [Fixed Job Scheduling Problem](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X87900370) : each job has a fixed start and end time and a value and the aim is to maximizes the value of jobs completed by identical machines (in your case, the value is 1 for any job). The only difference is that you have an interval of availability for the processors. Since you just want to know if it is possible to assign all the jobs, you can add fictive jobs on the unavailable slots of your processors. In your second example, you can add a job from 8 to 9, and another from 7 to 8.

You hence can solve this problem in polynomial time, by slightly adapting the algorithm provided in the attached article.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the reduction proof, but doesn't this fall under the category then of 'scheduling with non-identical machines is NP-complete' part of the paper (i.e. the problem in which machines are non-identical and each job has a subset of machines on which it can be processed)?

Comment: No it does not fall into this category. Let me show that there is a solution to the problem where where machine i is available from s(i) to e(i) (call this problem P1) if and only if there is a solution to the problem P2 where all machines are available and there are some additional jobs from 0 to s(i) and from e(i) to END for any i. Clearly, if P1 has a solution, so does P2. So let us prove the opposite.

Comment: Take the fictive job starting at 0 that is the longest: clearly this job can only be processed by the machine for which we designed it (or another one with the same starting availability time, we don't care). Take then the second longest fictive job, and so on. Do the same for the fictive jobs at the end, and you come to your initial problem that consists in trying to find an assignment of your non-fictive jobs to the non-always available machines.

Comment: If you agree with the answer, could you please validate it to make it clearer plse ?